# How can we take backup of one single schema with Data in SQL server, data is in billions

Tags: sql-server

I have a Database which has around 100 schemas. Out of this I want to take backup of single schema which has around millions/billions record per table, is there a method to do so?

I want to do it once as data is consuming lot of space, and backup is necessary so that we can restore data back on demand by customer.

I am using SQL Sever 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, taking backup of single schema is not possible. However you can transfer all your tables belong to one schema to a specific filegroup. Then you can choose "**Files and filegroups**" as Backup component by making Recovery model NOT Simple .